# IntelliJ and xDebug - xdebug.file_link_format

Tags: intellij-idea, xdebug, phpstorm

I've searched much time about IntelliJ IDEA 12 and the `xdebug.file_link_format` configuration value.

I found nothing which works...

- Using protocols like "idea", "intellij", "txmt", or other protocols doesn't work.
- I found nothing about a plugin which register the IntelliJ protocol...

Is it possible to use the xdebug file links with IntelliJ IDEA or PhpStorm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and No.

**No** -- there is no **proper built-in** support for this. Watch this ticket for details: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879

**Yes** -- you may find some workaround, at very least the aforementioned ticket has recipes for Mac OS (using AppleScript) or via Remote Call etc.

---

#### Update: as of [PhpStorm 8](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879#comment=27-747386) you may use:

```
xdebug.file_link_format = "phpstorm://open?file=%f&line=%l"
```

Comment: [Nice. Thank you.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879#comment=27-417625)

Comment: [PHPStorm 8 now supports `xdebug.file_link_format = "phpstorm://open?file=%f&line=%l"`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879#comment=27-747386)

Comment: @LazyOne Do you know whether that feature is still supported? I can't find any documentation about it, and using PhpStorm 2020.2, there is no `phpstorm` protocol handler being registered in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box, but it is possible to get the links to work. I have this working with Windows 7, Firefox and PhpStorm 10 - in this example, I'm using the protocol `phpstorm://`, but this will work regardless of the name.

- create a custom protocol handler: Any executable will do, here I have modified a WScript from https://pla.nette.org/en/how-open-files-in-ide-from-debugger . Save as run-editor.js :

`// note: edit the path, with backslashes escaped`

`var editor = '"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PhpStorm 143.434\\bin\\PhpStorm.exe" nosplash --line %line% "%file%"';`

`var url = WScript.Arguments(0);`

`var match = /^phpstorm:\/\/open\/\?file=(.+)&line=(\d+)$/.exec(url);`

`if (match) {`

`var file = decodeURIComponent(match[1]).replace(/\+/g, ' ');`

`var command = editor.replace(/%line%/g, match[2]).replace(/%file%/g, file);`

`var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");`

`shell.Exec(command.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'));`

`}`

- create the protocol in registry: create the following as `editor.reg` and import to Registry. Note that you again need to double-escape the path to the above file, and set it to wherever yours is saved:

`REGEDIT4`

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phpstorm]`

`@="URL:phpstorm Protocol"`

`"URL Protocol"=""`

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phpstorm\shell\open\command]`

`@="wscript \"C:\\path\\to\\run-editor.js\" \"%1\""`

- enable the protocol in Firefox:
  in `about:config`, create a "logical value" named
  `network.protocol-handler.expose.phpstorm` and set it to `false`
- open one such link in Firefox, e.g. `phpstorm://open?file=somefile.html&line=123` - it should open in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment from @gapple, this will make Xdebug link to the file/link in PhpStorm:

`xdebug.file_link_format = "phpstorm://open?file=%f&line=%l"`

I tested this in PhpStorm 10 on Mac and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ad to the `php.ini` file in the `[xdebug]` section the following line:

`xdebug.file_link_format = "phpstorm://open?file=%f&line=%l"`

Then restart your web server (Apache for me on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

The REST API is probably the best option now:

```
http://localhost:63342/api/file%f:%l
```

Wrapping in a javascript protocol and AJAX request allows the permission approval to be saved so you don't have to approve every time you click:

```
javascript: var r = new XMLHttpRequest; r.open('get', 'http://localhost:63342/api/file%f:%l');r.send()
```

API specs:
https://www.develar.org/idea-rest-api/